# Callback Constraint doesn't show paylod (Symfony Validator Component)

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

My controller code:

```
public function postFilesAction(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $requestCredentials = RequestCredentials::fromRequest($request);
    $errors = $validator->validate($requestCredentials);

...
```

validate method in RequestCredentials (Callback constraint).

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback(payload = {"errorCode" = "FILE_FILE_URL"})
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if (! ($this->fileExistsAndValid() || $this->fileUrlExistsAndValid())) {
        $context->buildViolation('Neither file nor file_url is present.')->addViolation();
    }
}
```

Callback works as expected, but the value of `$constraintViolation->$constraint->$payload` is null.

When I'm trying to use payload in other Constraints (NotBlank, for example), it works (I can see it in `ConstraintViolation` object).

Is it Symfony bug or am I doing somethings wrong? Should I use some other solution to my problem? (I need to check if there's at least one of two fields (`file` or `file_url`) present in request).

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 3.0 you cannot easily access the payload in the callback when using the `Callback` constraint. Starting with Symfony 3.1, the payload will be passed as an additional argument to the callback (see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15092 and https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16909).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry it took me so long to reply. Unfortunately, your answer didn't help me a lot. I saw those issue and pull request. The trouble was in that Callback constraint didn't have the content of `$payload` variable from the moment of creation.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I thought you wanted to access the payload inside your callback instead of requesting it after validation has happened.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this problem with following code in the assertion:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback(payload = {"error_code" = "1"}, callback = "validate", groups = {"Default", "RequestCredentials"})
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    // some validation code
}
```

I think the problem was because of the [Symfony Callback constraint](http://Symfony%5CComponent%5CValidator%5CConstraintshttps://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/3.0/Constraints/Callback.php) constructor:

```
public function __construct($options = null)
{
    // Invocation through annotations with an array parameter only
    if (is_array($options) && 1 === count($options) && isset($options['value'])) {
        $options = $options['value'];
    }
    if (is_array($options) && !isset($options['callback']) && !isset($options['groups'])) {
        $options = array('callback' => $options);
    }
    parent::__construct($options);
}
```

When it is given `$options = ['payload' => [...]]` (what happened in my case) it turns it into `$options = ['callback' => ['payload' => [...]]]`
and then '$payload' data becomes inacessable in `ConstraintViolation` object.

But I'm still not sure whether it's Symfony imperfection or me not getting something and using it wrong.

Comment: This looks like an error to me. I proposed a fix for this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/18298